# Sequence of points in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> I have to check if the set of points $p_n = (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is closed in the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2, d_R)$, where $d_R$ is the river metric.

Intuition tells me that this is an open set, but I don't know how to show that.

Edit: the river metric is defined as follows:

if $x_1 = x_2$

$d_R((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = |y_1 - y_2|$

else
$d_R((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = |x_1 - x_2| + |y_1| + |y_2|$

Comment: What is your definition of the river metric?

Comment: Note that $d_R(p_n,(0,0))=\frac{1}{n}+0+\left|\frac{1}{n}-0\right|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore, $p_n\to (0,0)$ as $n\to\infty$, while $(0,0)$ is not a point of the form $\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: I've edited the question to add my definition of the river metric

Comment: Is is equivalent to the standard metric?

Comment: Warning: Open and closed are NOT opposite terms. Many sets are neither open nor closed.

Comment: @topologicalmagician No, for example the sequence $q_n=(1/n,1)$ is not Cauchy for $d_R$, since $d_R((1/n,1),(1/m,1))=\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right|+2\geq2$, while it is Cauchy for $d((1/n,1),(1/m,1))=\sqrt{(1/n-1/m)^2+(1-1)^2}$.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate intuitively the $x$-axis is like a river in the forest $\Bbb R^2$ and the only paths in the forest are parallel to the $y$-axis. So to get from one point to another we can travel along these paths, directly if the first coordinates are equal, and using two paths and the river if they’re not.

Answer (score 1):

The set (a sequence really) has $(0,0)$ as a limit point, so is not closed. And it has no interior points, as open balls are uncountable.